# Google charts on side menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

I am trying to add google charts on side menu. 
Here is my file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/css/jquery.sliding_menu.css">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
    <!-- Menu -->

    </div>
    <!-- Contenido -->
  </div>

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="src/js/jquery.sliding_menu.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#menu ul').sliding_menu_js({
            header_title:'Nombre sitio web!',
            header_logo: "http://placehold.it/250x120"
        });

    });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the code to slide the side menu.

```
(function ($) {
    'use strict';
    $.fn.extend({
        sliding_menu_js: function (opciones) {

            // Configuraci贸n Base por defecto
            var config = {
                header_title: false,
                header_logo: false,
                toggle_button: true,
                transitionSpeed: 0.5,
                easing: 'ease'
            };

            if (opciones) {
                jQuery.extend(config, opciones);
            }

            // Se agregan elementos b谩sicos
            $('<div/>', { id: 'sliding_menu_js_btn'}).appendTo('body');

            $('<div/>', { id: 'sliding_menu_js', class: 'cerrado' }).appendTo('body');

            $('<div/>', { class: 'header' }).appendTo('#sliding_menu_js');

            $('<ul/>').appendTo('#sliding_menu_js');

            $('<div/>', { id: 'sliding_menu_js_over' }).appendTo('body');


            // Se agrega un padding top para mostrar todo el contenido del sitio
            $('body').css('padding-top', '60px');

            // Se copia el menu original
            $('#sliding_menu_js ul').append($(this).html());

            // Se eliminan elementos innecesarios
            $('.divider').remove();
            $('#sliding_menu_js ul').removeClass();
            $('#sliding_menu_js ul li').removeClass();
            $('#sliding_menu_js ul li a').removeClass();

            // Titulo
            if (config.header_title) {
                $('#sliding_menu_js .header').prepend("<h3>" + config.header_title + "</h3>");
                $('#sliding_menu_js_btn').append("<h3>" + config.header_title + "</h3>");
            }

            // Logo
            if (config.header_logo) {
                $('#sliding_menu_js .header').prepend("<img src='" + config.header_logo + "' />");
            }

            // Transici贸n
            $('#sliding_menu_js').css('transition', 'right ' + config.transitionSpeed + 's ' + config.easing);


            $('#sliding_menu_js_btn').click(function () {
                toggle();
            });

            $('#sliding_menu_js_over').click(function () {
                ocultar();
            });

            // Al presionar cualquier enlace dentro del menu
            $('#sliding_menu_js ul li a').click(function () {
                // ocultar();
            });

            // Muestra/Oculta el panel
            function toggle (){
                if ( $('#sliding_menu_js').hasClass('open') ) {
                    ocultar();
                } else {
                    mostrar();
                }
            }

            // Muestra la barra lateral
            function mostrar(){
                if ( $('#sliding_menu_js').hasClass('cerrado') ) {
                    $('#sliding_menu_js').css('right','5px');
                    $('#sliding_menu_js').removeClass('cerrado');
                    $('#sliding_menu_js').addClass('open');
                    $('#sliding_menu_js_over').show();
                };
            }

            // Oculta la barra lateral
            function ocultar(){
                if ( $('#sliding_menu_js').hasClass('open') ) {
                    $('#sliding_menu_js').css('right','-250px');
                    $('#sliding_menu_js').removeClass('open')
                    $('#sliding_menu_js').addClass('cerrado')
                    $('#sliding_menu_js_over').hide();
                };
            }
        }
    })
})(jQuery)
```

I am using google charts which is working properly, the issue is where should I add the google charts code so that it is inside the side menu and is visible when the side menu slides on to the left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a side pane navigation you can have div with classes bs-sidebar in Bootstrap.
The following code will create a side pane for you when in 3/12 part of page in rest 9/12 you can let your content go. You can increase or drecrease the size of pane upon your reuirements.

```
<div class="container bs-docs-container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="bs-sidebar hidden-print affix-top" role="complementary">
<ul class="nav bs-sidenav">
<li>
<a href="#">Put your Side Pane Options Here</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<div id="IntroductionPane" class=" col-md-9" role="main">
Main Content Goes Here
</div>
</div><!--Ends Row-->
</div><!--Ends Container Div-->
```